# Problems with Lists in R

Tags: r

I am a little bit puzzled when using lists of lists. If I try the following code, I get an error and I don't understand why:

```
library(tibble)

data <- list()
data[1][[1]] <- tibble(year = rep(2010,4)) # works
data[1][[2]] <- tibble(year = rep(2011,4)) # gives me an error

# Warning message:
#   In data[1][[2]] <- tibble(year = rep(2011, 4)) :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any help on this, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = list()
data[[1]] = list()
data[[1]][[1]] = tibble(year = rep(2010,4))
data[[1]][[2]] = tibble(year = rep(2011,4))
```

output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
# A tibble: 4 × 1
   year
  <dbl>
1  2010
2  2010
3  2010
4  2010

[[1]][[2]]
# A tibble: 4 × 1
   year
  <dbl>
1  2011
2  2011
3  2011
4  2011
```

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because `data[1][[2]] <- tibble(year = rep(2011, 4))` attempts to add a new column `year` to the tibble it obtained by running `data[1]`. It is generally [advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el#:%7E:text=For%20lists%2C%20one%20generally%20uses,whereas%20%5B%20allows%20indexing%20by%20vectors.) to use double brackets when working with lists.

To illustrate why, see the output of the following code:

```
l <- list()
l[1] <- tibble(year = rep(2010,4))
l
[[1]]
[1] 2010 2010 2010 2010

# subsetting with [1] can be surprising
l[1][1][1][1][1][1][1]
[[1]]
[1] 2010 2010 2010 2010
```

a `tidyverse`-like way to construct such nested list, avoiding repetition in code, would be

```
#using tidyverses' purrr package
data <- list(purrr::map(2010:2011, ~ tibble(year = rep(.x, 4))))
```

An alternative, which one should be wary off, see
the second circle of [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) on growing objects, is to properly initialize a list, and then populate it.

```
# initialize, then fill
data <- list(rep(list(NULL), 2))
data[[1]][[1]] <- f(2010)
data[[1]][[2]] <- f(2011)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of tibbles you index like this.

```
data <- list()

data[1][[1]] <- tibble(year = rep(2010,4))
data[2][[1]] <- tibble(year = rep(2011,4))


str(data)

# List of 2
#  $ : tibble [4 x 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#   ..$ year: num [1:4] 2010 2010 2010 2010
#  $ : tibble [4 x 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#   ..$ year: num [1:4] 2011 2011 2011 2011
```